# How to make macOS open RAR archive in Terminal using unrar on double-click?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, rar

I want to make macOS open RAR files: On double-click macOS should open Terminal with command `unrar x /path/filename.rar`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch Automator.app and create a new Application.

Add the "Run Shell Script" action. As unrar seems to be a command installed in `/usr/local/bin/`, set the Shell type to `/bin/bash`, and **Pass input** to `as arguments`.

You'll be given a free bit of shell code, which you can easily modify:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/bin/unrar x "$f"
done
```

Save the app. Then select a .rar file, choose File > Get Info, and change the default handler for that type to your new app.

Alternatively, there are plenty of third-party apps that unwrap rar and other archive types, such as [TheUnarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com).